# Excel VBA Refresh a UserForm from another UserForm command button

Tags: excel, vba, refresh

I currently have UserForm1 that contains multipage and a listbox.  The listbox essentially shows a range of data from the excel sheet itself.

I have set up Userform2 as a popup to fill in information that is added to the excel sheet which is then displaced in the listbox in Userform1.

In essence the user navigates to the listbox, clicks a command button, a popup appears and the user complete the information, clicks "ok" and it it is then displayed in the listbox.

The issue I have is that I am unable to get the listbox up refresh when the user clicks "ok".

The code I have in the "ok" command button is:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


 Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Exchange")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = TextBox1.Text
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow).Value = TextBox2.Text
    ws.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = TextBox3.Text
    ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = TextBox4.Text
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = TextBox5.Text
    ws.Range("H" & LastRow).Value = ComboBox1.Text





UserForm2.Hide

Forms!UserForm1.ListBox1.Requery
Forms!UserForm1.Repaint


End Sub
```

I currently get Run-time error '424' Object required.

Any suggestions on how I can refresh?

Many thanks

Comment: there should be no use for `Forms!`... try `UserForm1.ListBox1.Requery` and `UserForm1.Repaint`

Comment: Many thanks for that.  I have just changed the end part as suggested and I get "Compile error: Method or data member not found"?

Comment: How's UserForm1 listbox filled? By "AddItem" or "RowSource"? In the latter case, what's the statement setting its RowSource property?

Comment: It is filled under Private Sub Userform_Initialize    ListBox1.RowSource = "Exchange!A2:I" & Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

A Userform `ListBox` doesn't have a `Requery` property. If you have set the `Row Source` property to a range address then the values in the `ListBox` will update, I believe, whenever the sheet recalculates.

The following code shows this:

```
Const ADDR As String = "A1:A5"

Sheet1.Range(ADDR).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

UserForm1.Show False
UserForm1.ListBox1.RowSource = ADDR

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Sheet1.Range("A5").Value = 6
MsgBox "Ready to see change in listbox."
Application.Calculate
```

If you have disabled autocalculation then you won't see a change in your `ListBox`. There may well be other means of disabling the update but I'm pretty sure that `EnableEvents` and `ScreenUpdating` aren't amongst them.

You should check your `Calculation` property and if you have disabled it then either coerce a calculation `Application.Calculate` or re-set the property `Application.Calculation  = xlCalculationAutomatic`.

Comment: Hi,

I have double checked and the calculations are still automatic.  

If on UserForm1 I add a command button `UserForm_Initialize` then everything updates fine.

The issue is that I want this to happen from a close button on UserForm2 (is the form to fill in data).  If I add `UserForm_Initializ`e to this action I then get "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: @Edd, can you update your question with the code from both Userforms. I don't entirely understand what you're saying and it'd be easier to see all the code.